# Adding to long complicated query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query of

```
Select 
cards.card_id, 
  cards.item_name, 
  cards.meta_description,
  cards.description, 
  '' as Weight,
  '' as UPC,
  '' as Part,
  cards.seo_keywords,
  concat('',cards.card_id,'_shadow.png') AS ImageURL,
  lookup_details.value,
  concat('ARTIST - ', card_import.artist) AS Brand,
 replace(lower(concat( 'http://www.test.com/', pcat.seoname,'/',cat.seoname, '/', cards.seoname, '.htm' )),' ','+') AS link,
            concat(pcat.name,' > ',cat.name) as Merchant,
 round(min(card_lookup_values.card_price), 2) AS 'price',
 min(cast(lookup_details.value as signed)) as 'quantity'

FROM
  cards
  left join card_import on card_import.card_id = cards.card_id
  join card_lookup_values on card_lookup_values.card_id = cards.card_id
           INNER JOIN card_categories cc ON cards.card_id = cc.card_id AND cards.card_live = 'y' AND cards.active = 'y' AND cc.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories cat ON cat.category_id = cc.category_id AND cat.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories pcat ON cat.parent_category_id = pcat.category_id
INNER JOIN card_lookup_values as card_values ON cards.card_id = card_values.card_id
INNER JOIN lookup_details ON card_lookup_values.lookup_detail_id = lookup_details.lookup_detail_id

WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7,lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
GROUP BY
  cards.card_id
ORDER BY
  cards.card_id
```

I think I have everything set right, but I keep getting an error in Navicat that says I have an error near  **

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
GROUP BY
  cards.card_id
ORDER BY
  cards.card_' at line 28
```

**

Did I just miss something in this?

Comment: Do you not need a boolean operator between these two in your "where" clause? WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7,lookup_details.lookup_id= 40

Comment: I might have to get one of those personalized baby bibs - I am a messy eater! — *"Stand back please, programmer eating."*

Comment: Wow. 7 answers within a minute (counting the comment), and all basically got it. That's like a firing squad. Trivial errors shouldn't get anywhere near here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to AND or OR (whichever is appropriate) your WHERE conditions together.

```
...
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7 AND lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
...

...
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7 OR lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you hav an extra comma

```
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7,lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
```

should be

```
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7 AND lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper SQL syntax uses the `AND` keyword in a `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE blahblah = blah AND trala = la
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7,lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
```

should be

```
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7 AND lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
```

don't forget the semicolon at the end too!

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7,lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
```

to this

```
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7 and lookup_details.lookup_id= 40
```